# setFrame working on iOS7 but not anymore on iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uiscrollview, ios7

I just switched to iOS7 SDK.
My app worked fine before this on iOS6 but not anymore except it works fine on iOS7 now.

I have a scrollView with page control to show 3 different tabs with the following settings:

```
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

I add on this scrollView my 3 views which I load from 3 different storyboards:

```
    UIStoryboard *timelineStoryboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"timelineStoryboard" bundle:nil];
TabBarViewController *mainVC=[timelineStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.currentViewController =mainVC;
[mainVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 20, mainVC.view.frame.size.width, mainVC.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:mainVC.view];
[self addChildViewController:mainVC]; 

UIStoryboard *expenseStoryboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"expenseStoryboard" bundle:nil];
TabBarViewController *leftVC=[expenseStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.leftViewController =leftVC;
[leftVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, leftVC.view.frame.size.width, leftVC.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.leftViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, leftVC.view.frame.size.width, leftVC.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:leftVC.view];
[self addChildViewController:leftVC];


UIStoryboard *dashboardStoryboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
TabBarViewController *rightVC=[dashboardStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashboardVC"];
self.leftViewController =rightVC;
[rightVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(640, 20, rightVC.view.frame.size.width, rightVC.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:rightVC.view];
[self addChildViewController:rightVC];
```

On iOS6, these 3 views are display on top of each other whereas on iOS7 they are correctly displayed (on with abscissa 0, one with x=320 and another one with x=640).
Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: I put it back to see if it worked, but no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I used intermediary variables and it worked. Don't why though.
If anyone has the answer, I'd be glad to hear it.

Anyway, the code which worked is here:

```
UIStoryboard *dashboardStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
TabBarViewController  *rightVC = [dashboardStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashboardVC"];

UIView *dashboardView = rightVC.view;
[dashboardView setFrame:CGRectMake(640,
                                   20,
                                   320,
                                   screenHeight+20)];

[self.scrollView addSubview:dashboardView];
[self addChildViewController:rightVC];
```